# Issue in android sqlite rawQuery with ORDER BY?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get data in an order by executing rawQuery with join conditions. but i am unable to get expected result.
below is my query.

```
String queryString =  "SELECT  DISTINCT   B.MakeID , B.Make  FROM MakeList B JOIN  BodyStyle BS ON B.Makeid = BS.makeid AND BS.Year = 2012 ORDER BY B.Make ASC";
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` can be your source of problem here. Anyways, you need to provide sample data, what you are expecting and what you are getting.

Comment: I need to get ordered make fields from MakeList table.The above query is working fine in SQLite Manager and it is returning ordered make list. but android it is not.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is no need to write ASC coz it is bydefault ascending order to display result so write simple ORDER BY B.Make and second thing specify what you need in results and post database fields also.

Comment: I need to get ordered make fields from MakeList table.The above query is working fine in SQLite Manager and it is returning ordered make list. but android it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your databases match.  You may have db data that your SQLite Manager is accessing that may be different that what is on your Android device.  That is probably causing your unexpected behavior.